# прилагательное + ОЧЕНЬ

Tags: словоупотребление

> Самодельные суши? Ебаторно очень... проще заказать.

Does this word order express anything different than **очень ебаторно**? Is it perhaps more "too" than "very" in this order?

Comment: More examples! I'm Russian and I meet *Ебаторно* for the first time.
<br/>
This is more common:
<br/>
*Геморно* (comes from hemorrhoids, slang too) = hard.
<br/>
*Напряжно* (more neutral) = hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two phrases (with *очень* before and after the *ебаторно*) mean pretty much the same thing.  There may be a slight difference based on the emphasis in the spoken voice.

You are right to say that it's perhaps more "too" then "very".

Generally there may be a very slight difference in the emphasis, based on whether *очень* is used before or after.  When it's used after the adverb, the emphasis is on the adverb and *очень* is closer in meaning to "too".  If it's used before the adverb, then the actual tone of voice would determine the emphasis.  If it is on *очень*, than it's closer to "very", if it's on the adverb, then it's closer to "too".

Answer (score 2):

This word order puts focus on **Ебаторно** (means "I think this is hard. Let's do do it simpler"). Actually **очень** here does not mean anything. It just make the speech smoother. Otherwise the speaker should make a long pause before **проще заказать**.

**очень ебаторно** puts focus on **очень**. It may mean "I have such an experience and never do it again"). However to keep the style of the conversation **очень** should be replaced with some offensive synonymy.

BTW is very offensive. However it's ok to say this to your friend if your friend uses to say "fuck" all the time.

Answer (score 1):

No, the reverse word order here adds **neither extra meaning nor emphasis**, but in some context it may be used for better rhythmic organization of speech (as in poetry, not using such an adverb, of course). Such word order (*очень* after an adjective or an adverb) is mainly possible in a simple phrase defining something and it's likely to become unnatural or even ungrammatical in a complicated sentence where those 2 words would be of less importance.